# How do I get more carnations?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I got a red carnation for Father's Day (or something), and according to the Animal Crossing wiki, [carnations are given on event days](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Flower) but they don't say more than that.

Which event days give carnations? Are there other colors of carnations? Can I breed carnations just like other flowers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Wikia's Animal Crossing - Flower](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Flower#Carnation) page, there are 3 varieties of carnations, Pink carnations can only be obtained on Mother's Day (May 10th). Red carnations can only be obtained on Father's Day (June 21). White carnations can be grown by placing a red carnation and a pink one to create a hybrid.

You can also grow red and pink carnations, but only from existing red and pink carnations. In other words, you cannot grow any pink carnations without at least 2 pink carnations. The same thing is true of red ones. With only red carnations, you will never be able to grow pink ones, and vice versa.

Your best bet would be to try and find a person who actively grows carnations and borrow some from that person's town. Otherwise, you will have to wait until May 10th before you can get pink carnations.

Comment: I agree 100% bit you can change the date to may 10th if you don't care about the log or anything. This also allows ou to get ten more coins!

Comment: You can get any carnations from pink. I've gotten two reds and white.

Answer (score 0):

try watering that red carnation in the morning they might be more thonky.com has a good hybrid page with the different carnation flowers. Try visiting the international island and trade friend codes with someone or get a acnl instagram account you can meet a lot of talented kind crossers. :)